# C# Difference betwen passing multiple enum values with pipe and ampersand

Tags: c#, .net, parameters, enums, parameter-passing

C# accepts this:

```
this.MyMethod(enum.Value1 | enum.Value2);
```

and this:

```
this.MyMethod(enum.Value1 & enum.Value2);
```

Whats the difference?

Comment: That passing `enum.Value1 & enum.Value2` is very unlikely.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**When you do `|`, you select both. When you do `&`, you only what overlaps.**

Please note that these operators only make sense when you apply the `[Flags]` attribute to your enum. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx for a complete explanation on this attribute.

As an example, the following enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum TestEnum
{
    Value1 = 1,
    Value2 = 2,
    Value1And2 = Value1 | Value2
}
```

And a few test cases:

```
var testValue = TestEnum.Value1;
```

Here we test that `testValue` overlaps with `Value1And2` (i.e. is part of):

```
if ((testValue & TestEnum.Value1And2) != 0)
    Console.WriteLine("testValue is part of Value1And2");
```

Here we test whether `testValue` is exactly equal to `Value1And2`. This is of course not true:

```
if (testValue == TestEnum.Value1And2)
    Console.WriteLine("testValue is equal to Value1And2"); // Will not display!
```

Here we test whether the combination of `testValue` and `Value2` is exactly equal to `Value1And2`:

```
if ((testValue | TestEnum.Value2) == TestEnum.Value1And2)
    Console.WriteLine("testValue | Value2 is equal to Value1And2");
```

Answer (score 10):

```
this.MyMethod(enum.Value1 | enum.Value2);
```

This will bitwise 'OR' the two enum values together, so if `enum.Value` is 1 and `enum.Value2` is 2, the result will be the enum value for 3 (if it exists, otherwise it will just be integer 3).

```
this.MyMethod(enum.Value1 & enum.Value2);
```

This will bitwise 'AND' the two enum values together, so if `enum.Value` is 1 and `enum.Value2` is 3, the result will be the enum value for 1.

Answer (score 7):

One is bitwise-or, the other is bitwise-and. In the former case this means that all the bits that are set in one or the other are set in the result. In the latter case this means that all the bits that are in common and set in both are set in the result. You can read about [bitwise operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) on Wikipedia.

Example:

```
enum.Value1 = 7  = 00000111
enum.Value2 = 13 = 00001101
```

then

```
enum.Value1 | enum.Value2 = 00000111
                           |00001101
                          = 00001111
                          = 15
```

and

```
enum.Value1 & enum.Value2 = 00000111
                           &00001101
                          = 00000101   
                          = 5
```

Answer (score 4):

This question has a nice explanation: [What does the [Flags] Enum Attribute mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/enum-flags-attribute)

Comment: i agree with you this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8480/1592884 had the best none confusing response

Answer (score 2):

Enum parameters can be binary numbers, for example

```
enum WorldSides
{
    North=1,
    West=2,
    South=4,
    East=8
}

WorldSides.North | WorldSides.West = both values -> 3
```

So, | is used to combine the values.

Use & to strip some part of the value, for example

```
if (ws & WorldSides.North)
{
     //  ws has north component
}
```